# How to update a list with an onclick event

Tags: javascript

I have tried to recreate based upon suggestion to make easier to read.

http://jsfiddle.net/dcaLsx24/

```
    <ul>
        <li id="tens">Output 10 count</li>
        <li id="twts">Output 20 count</li>
        <li id="thtrs">Output 30 count</li>
        <li id="frtys">Output 40 count</li>
        <li id="fifs">Output 50 count</li>
    </ul>
    <p id="arrayout"></p>
    <script>
        var seatingArray = [
            [10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10],
            [10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10],
            [10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10],
            [10, 10, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 10, 10],
            [10, 10, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 10, 10],
            [10, 10, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 10, 10],
            [20, 20, 30, 30, 40, 40, 30, 30, 20, 20],
            [20, 30, 30, 40, 50, 50, 40, 30, 30, 20],
            [30, 40, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 40, 30]
        ];

        // global counters for the seats

        <!--  Not optimized for IE but should work in FF, Chrome and Safari-->
        function start() {
            for (var i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
                for (var j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
                    //places a click event on every aserisk in the table
                    document.getElementById(i.toString() + j.toString()).addEventListener("click", processClick, false);
                } //for
            } //for


            // need reference to each list item

        } //start


        function processClick(evt) {
            var cellID = evt.target.getAttribute("id"); // obtains the id value of the asterisk clicked
            //evt.target.innerHTML = cellID;                // displays the id value of the asterisk clicked
            evt.target.innerHTML = "$$"; // writes $$ string back to html table cell

            seatingArray[parseInt(cellID.charAt(0))][parseInt(cellID.charAt(1))] = "$$";
            console.log(parseInt(cellID.charAt(0)) + " " + parseInt(cellID.charAt(1)));
            console.log(seatingArray[parseInt(cellID.charAt(0))][parseInt(cellID.charAt(1))]);
            outputArray(seatingArray);
            updatecount(seatingarray)
            evt.target.removeEventListener("click", processClick, false);
        } //endcheck

        //create other functions if needed here

        function updatecount(thearray) {
            var fifty = 0
            if (result.innherhtml = "50") document.getelementbyId('fifs').innerhtml =
                'fifty + 1'

        }

        // display array contents
        function outputArray(theArray) {
            var results = "<table>";

            // iterates through the set of one-dimensional arrays
            for (var row in theArray) {
                results += "<tr>";

                // iterates through the elements of each one-dimensional array
                for (var column in theArray[row]) {
                    results += "<td>" + theArray[row][column] + "</td>";
                } // end inner for

                results += "</tr>"; // close row
            } // end outer for

            results += "</table>"; // close table

            document.getElementById("arrayout").innerHTML = results;
        } // end function outputArray

        // runs start function once
        window.addEventListener("load", start, false);
    </script>
</body>
```

I'm trying to increment each count of each number clicked in table that is created:

```
    <li id="tens">Output 10 count</li>
    <li id="twts">Output 20 count</li>
    <li id="thtrs">Output 30 count</li>
    <li id="frtys">Output 40 count</li>
    <li id="fifs">Output 50 count</li>
```

So there is a 2d array that when the script is executed will show and when you click on each cell it will essentially sell the "seat" and the $$ will replace the price of it.  I'm just not sure how to have the list update based upon how many of each seat is sold.  Any advice is more than welcome!

Comment: Please read how to create a [mcve] and minimize your example accordingly.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow ;)

Comment: I specifically want to have this list update based on a the click event.  Sorry its a little tough to format in this forum than what im used to.

Comment: That's a lot of code to do very little. Why not create all this HTML with a loop, using a closure, adding click Events at the same time? You can have a higher level var increase onclick and test against it.

Comment: I'm somewhat new to html and javascript and have gone off a lot of examples and stuff.  is it a difficult thing to update the count of each number clicked?  I could easily do it in C++ but have no clue how to do it in javascript.

Comment: I've edited it to hopefully your liking felix.  I've tried to narrow down what my intentions of this post is.  I apologize for the bad layout.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick example for what you want added to your code. I updated your `updatecount` function. I changed `processClick` to pass the spans value to `updatecount`. Then instead of parsing that text for the current count I added a custom attribute to the HTML to hold the current value. Hopefully this helps you get started on your way. There is a lot of room to improve this code but I didn't want to rewrite everything you did and decided to just stick to the question you asked.

I also cleaned up your fiddle a bit and moved the relevant pieces to the sections they should have been in. Feel free to comment and ask anything you are unsure of with what I added.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/AtheistP3ace/dcaLsx24/1/

HTML:

```
<li data-current="0" id="tens">Output 10 count</li>
<li data-current="0" id="twts">Output 20 count</li>
<li data-current="0" id="thtrs">Output 30 count</li>
<li data-current="0" id="frtys">Output 40 count</li>
<li data-current="0" id="fifs">Output 50 count</li>
```

JS:

```
function updatecount(value) {
    var current, text;
    if (value == '10') {
        current = document.getElementById('tens');
        text = 'Output 10 count: ';
    }
    else if (value == '20') {
        current = document.getElementById('twts');
        text = 'Output 20 count: ';
    }
    else if (value == '30') {
        current = document.getElementById('thtrs');
        text = 'Output 30 count: ';
    }
    else if (value == '40') {
        current = document.getElementById('frtys');
        text = 'Output 40 count: ';
    }
    else if (value == '50') {
        current = document.getElementById('fifs');
        text = 'Output 50 count: ';
    }
    var currentValue = current.getAttribute('data-current');
    currentValue = parseInt(currentValue, 10) + 1;
    current.innerHTML = text + currentValue;
    current.setAttribute('data-current', currentValue);
}
```

Comment: Ohh I see now, it's starting to make sense.  Logically I wanted to do something similar but didn't quite know how.  I truly appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Hope this is what you needed.

http://jsfiddle.net/dcaLsx24/2/

Try clicking on the cells now, they should update the counts inside

I have added following 2 things

```
var counterObj = {
    "10": {counter:0, liId:"tens"},
    "20":{counter:0, liId:"twts"},
    "30":{counter:0, liId:"thtrs"},
    "40":{counter:0, liId:"frtys"},
    "50":{counter:0, liId:"fifs"}
};

function updateCountList ( cellContent) {
    var listCounter = counterObj[cellContent];
    if(listCounter) {
        listCounter.counter++;
        document.getElementById(listCounter.liId).textContent = "Output " + cellContent + " count = " + listCounter.counter;
    }
}
```

And made a call to the updateCountList inside

```
function processClick(evt) {
    var cellID = evt.target.getAttribute("id");     // obtains the id value of the asterisk clicked

    updateCountList(evt.target.textContent);
///....
```

Comment: Oh wow, your method is somewhat different than the other posted method.  I will study both of these, I truly appreciate the effort you put into this to help me out!

Answer (score 0):

You might want something easier to style your table. I suggest looking into flexbox. Loops are a timesaver and a lifesaver. Here is something to get you started. http://jsfiddle.net/inspiredtolive/g8mk63yj/

```
for (var i = 0; i < seatingArray.length; i++) {
    var row = document.createElement("row");
    document.body.appendChild(row);
    for (var j = 0; j < seatingArray[i].length; j++) {
        var block = document.createElement("div");
        var id = String(i) + String(j);
        block.setAttribute("id", id);
        block.innerHTML = seatingArray[i][j];
        row.appendChild(block);
        block.addEventListener("click", function (evt) {
            document.getElementById(evt.target.id).innerHTML = "$$";
        }, false);
    }
}
```